# Change in file after creating FileOutputStream object even without writing anything into file

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

EDIT (for the sake of confusion): `null` has been written into the files "abc" and "efg".

After running the following code, the contents of file "abc" change which were initially `null` , and I get EOFException in every next execution :

```
ObjIStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("abc"));
M[][] objs  = (M[][]) ObjIStream.readObject();
FS.objs = objs;
ObjIStream.close();
```

Here, `FS.objs` is a static member of class FS of type `M[][]` type.

On the other hand, this one has no effect on the file and I don't get any Exceptions after any number of executions:

```
ObjIStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("abc"));
M[][] objs  = (M[][]) ObjIStream.readObject();
ObjIStream.close();
```

EDIT: I just found the trouble that exists in class FS in this form:

```
static{ 
 try { 
  ObjOStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("abc"));
  ObjOStream.close();
  ObjOStream = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream("efg"));
  ObjOStream.close(); 
 } 
 catch (IOException ex) { } 
}
```

How is it troubling anyways?

Comment: As you likely already know, reading a file should not change it, and cannot change the file itself, so you need to show us code that actually does this for us to be able to guess what might be wrong. Show your file and your [mcve] please.

Comment: Well I just found that I had this code in class FS: 
    `static{
        try {
            ObjOStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("abc"));
ObjOStream.close();
            ObjOStream = new java.io.ObjectOutputStream(new java.io.FileOutputStream("efg"));
ObjOStream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }`

Comment: yes, this is the trouble but how is it troubling anyways?

Comment: Please get that code out of comments and into your question. Code in comments is very difficult to read and understand. Secondly, please don't leave your catch blocks empty as that is a foolish and dangerous thing to do. At least print the stacktrace from within catch.

Comment: I have done this (your exception catching complain) only in the example, not in my actual code.

Comment: Can you please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: The code simply exits after this. Nothing else happens. As far as I have figured out, the `static` part of class FS is troubling. I have tried commenting them out. The problem gets resolved with that. But why is it troubling anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `new FileOutputStream("abc")` itself, which means `new FileOutputStream("abc", false)`. It cleans up all the data in file because you are not going to append anything. It calls `FileOutputStream.open(String name, boolean append)` which is a `private native` function. It erases everything in file in overwrite mode.